# Discord.js Trying to send embed, but just sends empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to send my channel an embed message, so when I type

```
**embed
```

in my channel it should return the embed message like

```
testbot    Title
           Description
```

But it just returns an empty message from my testbot (the bot name). I tried using

> message.channel.send(embedd, embed);

instead, but it gives me an error saying embed isn't declared. .send(content, options) is the format and embed is the option.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = "MY_TOKEN_ID";
const PREFIX = "**";

var name;
var usrAuth = 0;

bot.on("ready", function() {

    console.log("Ready");
});

bot.on("message", function(message) {

    console.log(message.content);

    if ( message.author.equals(bot.user)) 
        return;

    //  If the message doesn't begin with ** (Our prefix); do nothing 
    if( !message.content.startsWith(PREFIX))
        return;

    var argv = message.content.substr(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    console.log("argv: "+argv+", argv[1]: "+argv[1]+"");

    // "+VAR_NAME+" Allows you to print a variable
    switch(argv[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case "ping":
            message.channel.send("Ping!");
            break;
        case "embed":
            var embedd = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .addField("Title", "Description")
            message.channel.sendEmbed(embedd);
                // .catch(console.error);
            break;
        default:
            message.channel.send("Invalid commands");
    }

});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

My code is above, any ideas what's wrong? Changing var to const also does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the variable to `embed` and use this format

```
case "embed":
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .addField("Title", "Description")
    message.channel.send({embed});
        // .catch(console.error);
    break;
```

Comment: I just tried this and it still prints an empty string, although it doesn't give me the deprecation error anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by prints an empty string? When I do `**embed` alone it gives http://prntscr.com/fdvcfa which is exactly as you've described wanting it to do. Or am I missing a point? @Mad_Questionnaire

Comment: I think someone on my system is bugged, the bot doesn't seem to print things, but worked for you, prints this http://puu.sh/w5DFa/3a79b4fd17.png

Comment: Thank you so much! I had forgot the {} in the send action.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
case "embed":
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Title`)
    .setDescription(`Desc`)
    .addField("Title", "Description")
    message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
    // .catch(console.error);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

```
message.channel.send({ embed: embedd })
```

The method of sending using `sendEmbed` is now deprecated. For embeds using the send event, you need to specify it is an embed using `send({ embed: variable })` otherwise it will return an empty message which will (in future) make the bot exit.

Comment: Could you explain why and how exactly this answers the question?

Comment: The method of sending using sendEmbed is now deprecated. For embeds using the send event, you need to specify it is an embed using send({ embed: variable }) otherwise it will return empty message which will (in future) make the bot exit.

Comment: In Discord.js v13 it has been changed to { embeds [embed] }

Answer (score 0):

```
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(0x00AE86)
    .addField("Title", "Description")
    .setTimestamp()
if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send(embed);
```

This what I have used to make all the embed on my bot.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include what is different in your example or why the OP's code isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Discord.JS V13.x.x, you can use this function like this:

```
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1, embed2, ...] })
```